# Null arguments in the Fragment's bundle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've created a `Bundle` and put a `String` value in it. Then, I set it in a `Fragment`. However, when I try to read that value via `getArguments();` I'm getting `null`

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("flag", flagAbsentstr );
ExitFragment fragInfo = new ExitFragment();
fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);


private  void getArg(){
    Bundle args =this.getArguments();
    flagAbsentStr=args.getString("flag");
    flagAbsent=Integer.parseInt(flagAbsentStr);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getArg();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exit,container,false);
}
```

Comment: Is flagAbsentStr null/empty? Can you post the exact error?

Comment: Make sure that you show (with the help of a FragmentManager) exactly the Fragment instance for which you called setArguments().

Comment: try to call `getArg()` from `onCreate` in fragment

Comment: i test onCreate but not worked

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be setting the arguments on a local member named *fragInfo*, but you're attempting to get arguments on a different one, namely the *this* fragment.

Comment: both of them are exitFragment bro

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are putting your bundle **before** making transaction. For example, check below working navigation to another `Fragment` with `Bundle`.

```
final Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", buildingName);

final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction();

final Fragment fragment = new RoomListFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

ft.add(R.id.listview_fragment_container, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

**UPDATE**

To interact with already created Fragments (like `Tabs` you mentioned in comments), you need to check [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating) for ex. Just one of the examples to send data across `Fragment`s.

Comment: my fragment showed in tab view ...i didnt use these ```final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction();

final Fragment fragment = new RoomListFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

ft.add(R.id.listview_fragment_container, fragment);
ft.commit();```

Comment: @ParsaMayhem Then it's not about `Bundle` like you mentioned in the ticket. You just don't understand what to do at all. Check the updates.